# Quoting arguments in dynamic WHERE in OpenSQL

Tags: abap, opensql

I found this example how to create a dynamic WHERE:

```
REPORT ZII_RKP_TEST1.

DATA: cond(72) TYPE c,
      itab LIKE TABLE OF cond.

PARAMETERS: source(10) TYPE c, dest(10) TYPE c.

DATA wa TYPE spfli-cityfrom.

CONCATENATE 'CITYFROM = ''' source '''' INTO cond.
APPEND cond TO itab.

CONCATENATE 'OR CITYFROM = ''' dest '''' INTO cond.
APPEND cond TO itab.

CONCATENATE 'OR CITYFROM = ''' 'BAYERN' '''' INTO cond.
APPEND cond TO itab.

LOOP AT itab INTO cond.
  WRITE cond.
ENDLOOP.

SKIP.

SELECT cityfrom
  INTO wa
  FROM spfli
 WHERE (itab).
   WRITE / wa.
ENDSELECT.
```

Source: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Dynamic%2Bwhere%2Bclause

Above example uses static values like "BAYERN", but if I use arbitrary values, then I guess things could break for some special values like `'''`.

Is it necessary to do some quoting to make the dynamic WHERE unbreakable? And if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `cl_abap_dyn_prg=>quote( name )` should get used.

Example:

```
DATA(cond) = `country = 'DE' AND name = ` &&
             cl_abap_dyn_prg=>quote( name ).
```

Source: [SQL Injections Using Dynamic Tokens](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_inj_dyn_tokens_scrty.htm)

Thanks to Sandra Rossi for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape apostrophe in perform before adding them like below

```
PERFORM escape CHANGING source.
PERFORM escape CHANGING dest.

CONCATENATE 'CITYFROM = ''' source '''' INTO cond.
APPEND cond TO itab.

...

FORM escape CHANGING value TYPE c.
  REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '''' IN value WITH ''''''.
ENDFORM.
```

Latest ABAP versions included escape function details are [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenescape_functions.htm). But it is not included quote escaping. We can use static escape_quotes method on class cl_abap_dyn_prg like below.

```
CALL METHOD cl_abap_dyn_prg=>escape_quotes
  EXPORTING
    val    = source
  receiving
    out    = output.
```

Method making something look like above perform.

Comment: the escaping does only handle markup (HTML/XML), JSON, URL. I see no way to escape SQL. At least that's what I saw in the link you provided. But maybe I am blind.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I founded another class method and adding it to my answer.

Comment: Yes the class **CL_ABAP_DYN_PRG** is to be used ; it provides methods to escape the values, especially for preventing SQL injection, cf [SAP official documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_inj_dyn_tokens_scrty.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why that example is written that way, maybe it's an old piece of code.

1st: if you have access in your system to the "new" string syntax, you can just use something like

```
WHERE = |CITYFROM = '| && source && |'|.
```

2nd: the nice thing about string WHERE clauses is that you can just use variables as part of the string, I mean, if you just write something like

```
WHERE = 'CITYFROM = source'.
```

ABAP will transform that into proper SQL, as if you were writing your SQL properly.

(I wish I could explain myself properly, do not hesitate to ask if you have any doubt)

Comment: I guess in you answer SQL injection is possible.